# shooting the projectile in the way it is facing

Tags: unity, c#, projectile-physics

I got my projectile facing the right way thanks to @S. Tarık Çetin.
But now I want it to move the direction it's facing.
I think I need to use `RayCastHit2D` but I am not sure. If I need to use `RayCastHit2D` please tell me how.

I want to replace this part with `RayCastHit2D` or something else -:

```
MyRB.AddRelativeForce(new Vector2(1,1) * rocketSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Another thing - my projectile requires gravity. I think if I use `RayCastHit2D` the projectile will go in a straight line and not fall down. So if that's the case please tell me a better alternative. (so it acts like a tank projectile)

here is my code -:

Aim class -

```
       void Update(){
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.L))
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, -3.0f);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.J))
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 3f);
}
```

ProjectileController class -

```
     void Awake()
    {
        MyRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        MyRB.AddRelativeForce(new Vector2(1,1) * rocketSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

GunController class -:

```
void Update()
{

    //playershooting
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Fire1") > 0)
        fireRocket();

}

void fireRocket()
{

    if (Time.time > nextFire)
    {

        nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;

        Instantiate(bullet, guntip.position, guntip.rotation); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please tell me what do you want?! RayCastHit uses for find hit object in scene for example define when tank see enemy shot.your code is correct if you want shooting the projectile in the way it is facing you should use transform.right

```
    void fireRocket()
    {

        if (Time.time > nextFire)
        {

            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;

            GameObject clone = Instantiate(bullet, guntip.position, guntip.rotation) as GameObject; 
            clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.right * 10, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a bit confusing as you added everything in a single class or script, can do it using my scripts please.

Comment: just change  MyRB.AddForce(transform.right * 10, ForceMode2D.Impulse);